# Multiple Permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions

i have a java class, code as below.

```
public class PermisssionAction {

    public static void requestPermission(Activity activity, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Now i called its method in mainactivity to get permissions for app as below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
        PermisssionAction.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);



        Intent startupintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartupActivity.class);
        startActivity(startupintent);
        finish();


    }
}
```

Now i m not able to understand why it ask only one permission while running app on real mobile, whereas it ask all permission in one go at emulator.
Also suppose app took location permission on first time , when u open app again it will ask another permission pending and so on on real device. can u guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, only use `requestPermissions()` for `dangerous` permissions. `INTERNET`, for example, does not have a `protectionLevel` of `dangerous`.

Second, call `requestPermissions()` **once**, using a `String[]` of **all** the permissions that you are requesting. As it stands, you are calling `requestPermissions()` many times, with one permission per request.

Comment: but i am checking permission also before requesting, if u see the method closely. Only difference is, i m asking one by one instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a Permission Group. It will ask for Permission in User Interface. Refer : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html
2. Some gradle version are allow all permission automatically in Android Phone. (Old Gradle version with 6.0+ Devices)
3. User Easy permission for Better understanding and User. Else in native code, you need to check all permission are checked or Not. And provide callbacks on permission Acceptance. Search Easypermission for android. Its available in git.

By the way change " (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)" to Marshmallow in your existing code. For rest of the code, Refer : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html